# How to properly recover MIC in an audio processing app?

Tags: android, audio, monitoring, audio-processing

I developed a audio processing application to constantly run in the background and listen for a specific signal and when it does it sends an alarm to the user. This is all working great even when the user is in a phone call as it has a phone state listener implemented and allows to properly share the MIC. However, when other apps are making voice calls such as Whatsapp then it becomes problematic since those audio calls don't get detected by the phone state listener as they are technically not a phone call . Does anybody know how to properly monitor if any app is using VOIP?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a definitive solution however you can listen for the changing of AudioManager.getMode().
When a normal (non VOIp) voicecall is made the telephone App sets that mode to IN_CALL.
Usually other Apps that make VOIp calls sets that mode as IN_COMMUNICATION.
So you could remove the Listener and create a Thread that listens for AudioManager.getMode() changes and raise the Events you want for both modes.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I will try that approach